# how can i split a string inside curly braces?

Tags: java

I have a string which looks like this

```
[{"TransactionId":"3574780600039252015-12-24 T 14:22:03"
```

Now I want to split only the text where the "TransactionId" will be part one and after `:` will be the second part.

Code I've tried :

```
String[] transid_result = result.split(":");
String part1 = transid_result[0];
String part2 = transid_result[1];
```

The result is

- `part1` contains `[{"TransactionId`
- `part2` contains `"3574780600039252015-12-24 T 14`

I want `part2` to contain `"3574780600039252015-12-24 T 14:22:03"`

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: This seems like a JSON data, You should first convert it to JSON format and then do your required operation.

Comment: This is json and you should not be splitting the string yourself to try and get the properties. Look for a json library

Comment: like @nbokmans said, it's better to use a library that maps JSON formatted data to Java objects and vice versa.
You can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Comment: ok thanks alot for sharing your knowledge , will keep this in mind

Comment: User ```result.split(":", 2)```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could search for the first `:` and manually split by that:

```
int firstColon = result.indexOf(":");
String part1 = result.substring(0,firstColon);
String part2 = result.substring(firstColon+1, result.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the data will always be in this format, then you could use

```
String[] elements = result.split("\"");
String transactionId = elements[3];
```